# Center with line-height without height

Tags: html, css, centering, line-height

As you know, we can use the `line-height` property with a value that is equal to the `height` property of a container to vertically center a single line within that container:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

I have seen this method in many references, for example:

- [AtoZ CSS Quick Tip: How to Vertically Center Text and Icons](https://www.sitepoint.com/atoz-css-quick-tip-vertical/)
- [Centering Text with Line Height](https://riptutorial.com/css/example/20516/centering-text-with-line-height)
- [Center Text Vertically in CSS](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/css/css-center-text-vertically/#use-the-line-height-property-to-center-the-text-vertically-in-css)

Now the question is, why is the `height` property set? Is it necessary, or can we simply manage with `line-height` only?

Comment: `line-height` mainly added for `H1-H6, p, span etc.......` which have direct contents in it. `height` is for `block or inline-block`

Comment: @AmanSharma what you wrote makes no sense. *"span etc"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single-text is present, your line-height will be enough to vertically-center the text. It is because, since even 1 single line is present, equalling it out to 200px, will automatically set min-height to 200px.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Now, lets see with example where there is no-text.

Here, in this case, your line-height did not work, as there is no-text present. In this scenario, your `height:200px` would have come handy, as still there is no-text, it would have atleast provided 200px height even without any content (so here, if you want some height to always being present, even without any data, `height:200px` would be useful).

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is a *"single-text"*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan -  I meant a single-character-text, like `<p>a</p>`.